# Cannot remove all dockers from container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to remove stop all docker containers on my ubuntu server but i keep getting `"docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.` Here is the relevant part of my Github Action file:

```
  - name: Deploy
    env:
        DOCKER_USER: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
        DOCKER_PW: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PW }}
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
        host: ${{ secrets.DEVELOP_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.DEVELOP_USERNAME }}
        password: ""
        key: ${{ secrets.DEVELOP_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script: |
        ls
        sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
        sudo docker pull username/reponame
        sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
        sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -q)
        sudo docker run -d -e NODE_ENV=develop -p 3000:3000 username/reponame
```

Output: `"docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.`

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That means that  `$(docker ps -a -q)` was evaluated to nothing.

```
sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

> Output: "docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.

That is like whether you execute :

```
sudo docker stop
```

It cannot work. One or more container are expected as args.

Either ignore the error :

```
sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) || true
```

Or perform the stop on condition :

```
containerIds=$(docker ps -a -q)
if [[ -n $containerIds ]] ; then
  sudo docker stop $containerIds
fi
```

Comment: ... Or `docker ps -a -q | xargs -r docker stop`. The habitual use of `sudo` is a bad smell too.

Comment: Indeed. Overall with the `docker` command, `sudo` is not particularly required for some some specific subcommands (here `stop`)

Comment: Once you've done that `chmod` to loosen permissions on the Docker socket, you don't need `sudo` to run Docker commands at all.  (Also note that it's trivial to use `docker run` to edit things like `/etc/sudoers` on the host, so this may not be the security configuration you want.)

Comment: Thanks all - for some reason, if i don't type `sudo`, I get `docker: command not found` :(